# Unable to access/(auto)-mount SD card on Fedora 28

Tags: fedora, mount, kernel-modules, automounting, sd-card

I am trying to access SD cards on Fedora 28, but do not have any success. System info is as follows:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
Release:    28
Codename:   TwentyEight
```

I was not able to access different SD cards using two different card readers. Despite of being accessible on both macOS and Windows, none of them is shown in the Nautilus file browser, the desktop or elsewhere obvious.

The card readers are recognized by the system as per `lsusb` output:

```
$ lsusb -v
# some other USB devices
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               2.00
bDeviceClass            0 
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0        64
idVendor           0x058f Alcor Micro Corp.
idProduct          0x6362 Flash Card Reader/Writer
bcdDevice            1.29
iManufacturer           1 
iProduct                2 
iSerial                 3 
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
    (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              250mA
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         4
    bInterfaceNumber        0
    bAlternateSetting       0
    bNumEndpoints           2
    bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
    bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
    bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
    iInterface              0 
    Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
        Transfer Type            Bulk
        Synch Type               None
        Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
        Transfer Type            Bulk
        Synch Type               None
        Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0

# some other USB devices

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0dda:2027 Integrated Circuit Solution, Inc. USB 2.0 Card Reader
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               2.00
bDeviceClass            0 
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0        64
idVendor           0x0dda Integrated Circuit Solution, Inc.
idProduct          0x2027 USB 2.0 Card Reader
bcdDevice            1.6e
iManufacturer           1 
iProduct                2 
iSerial                 3 
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0x80
    (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         4
    bInterfaceNumber        0
    bAlternateSetting       0
    bNumEndpoints           2
    bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
    bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
    bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
    iInterface              5 
    Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
        Transfer Type            Bulk
        Synch Type               None
        Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
        Transfer Type            Bulk
        Synch Type               None
        Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0

# some other USB devices
```

I then had a look at the udev events while plugging a card in and out:

```
$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[701.434565] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:2/block/sde (block)
UDEV  [714.263816] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:2/block/sde (block)
KERNEL[748.477184] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:2/block/sde (block)
UDEV  [761.338940] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:2/block/sde (block)
```

In addition, I had a look at the kernel messages:

```
$ dmesg
[  603.846840] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  603.847749] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  605.703531] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic                CF 1.6E PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  605.704982] scsi 4:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic                MS 1.6E PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  606.509034] scsi 4:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic            MMC/SD 1.6E PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  606.510387] scsi 4:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic                SM 1.6E PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  606.511519] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  606.511943] sd 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[  606.512177] sd 4:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[  606.512408] sd 4:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[  608.924586] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  629.830776] sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  633.048754] sd 4:0:0:3: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  639.490479] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Both the output of `dmesg` and `udevadm monitor` are telling that the card should be shown as `sde`. However, `fdisk -l` does not list `sde`. Besides that, trying to mount the device manually, raises an error:

```
$ mount -t auto /dev/sde /mnt/
mount: /mnt: no medium found on /dev/sde.
```

I am not sure, whether the needed driver module is loaded properly, since there is no `mmc0`-like entry in the `dmesg` output (as I am used to know from Debian-based systems). `lsmod` does not list the `mmc0` kernel module either:

```
$ lsmod | grep mm
rtl8192c_common        61440  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                98304  3 rtl8192c_common,rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
```

The only `mmc`-like modules which seems to be available but are not loaded are `mmc_block` and `mmc_core`:

```
$ modprobe mm  # listing suggestions using tab auto-completion
mma7660    mmc_block  mmc_core   mms114
```

How could I solve this problem or at least narrow it down?

Comment: Are you saying that the same _adapter_ works in Windows?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That was actually a good hint. I double-checked the cards only. However, _both_ card readers / adapters tested (tested two different ones with several cards) seem to be faulty. After getting a third one, all cards are available as desired.

Comment: Those ultra cheap adapters have a failure rate that seems to hover between 90% and 100%. If you depend on this sort of media, it's probably worth spending a bit of money on a more reliable reader.

Comment: `sudo dnf reinstall udisks2`
solved the problem for me. [Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456654/241592)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in all *both* card readers I tested were faulty. However, please refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456654/183170) if you can eliminate hardware-related issues.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to `mount` this is too soon in the process. This message shows that the hardware was detected:

```
[  629.830776] sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

But you cannot mount a device unless it has a filesystem on it that is mountable. Take a look at the system using `lsblk` or `blkid` to see if the system recognizes the SD device(s).

Here's what the output will look like for reference:

*lsblk*

```
$ lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0 39.1G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot
├─sda2             8:2    0  500M  0 part
└─sda3             8:3    0 38.1G  0 part
  ├─vg00-lv_root 253:0    0 36.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg00-lv_swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

*blkid*

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="0cae38ac-44ea-4a16-9157-a8cbbf50e91b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="013c42ea-aa00-4713-926a-aca57c0bd552" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda3: UUID="sgVDOh-NI7x-l4sY-9fJv-uAlW-WfYY-YBoPBQ" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root: UUID="fa4accee-2965-4bc6-85aa-3ed4d0d2ae86" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_swap: UUID="998f50cb-a693-411c-aca3-33824ea5a204" TYPE="swap"
```

As a last suggestion you could try installing/re-installing `udisks2`. This was described in this AU Q&A titled: [Ubuntu 16.04 does not detect sd card reader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787088/ubuntu-16-04-does-not-detect-sd-card-reader), but I've had issues with this in the past as well on Fedora/CentOS too.

```
$ sudo yum reinstall udisks2

-or-

$ sudo dnf reinstall udisks2
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Howto
1) Download latest rpmfusion-free-release-stable rpm from
http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/

2) Install rpmfusion-free-release-stable rpm:

## rpm -Uvh rpmfusion-free-release-stable*rpm

3) Install fuse-exfat rpm package:

## dnf install fuse-exfat

https://fedora.pkgs.org/29/rpmfusion-free-x86_64/fuse-exfat-1.3.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm.html

[michaelmeyer@localhost ~]$ rpm -Uvh rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
error: open of rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm failed: No such file or directory

[michaelmeyer@localhost ~]$ sudo dnf install fuse-exfat

[sudo] password for michaelmeyer: 
Fedora Modular 30 - x86_64                       43 kB/s |  19 kB     00:00
Fedora Modular 30 - x86_64 - Updates             40 kB/s |  15 kB     00:00
Fedora 30 - x86_64 - Updates                     36 kB/s |  14 kB     00:00
Fedora 30 - x86_64                               95 kB/s |  19 kB     00:00
google-chrome-beta                               16 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00
google-chrome                                    20 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00
RPM Fusion for Fedora 30 - Free - Updates       670 kB/s | 375 kB     00:00
RPM Fusion for Fedora 30 - Free                 725 kB/s | 735 kB     00:01

## Dependencies resolved.

## Package          Architecture Version               Repository            Size

Installing:
 fuse-exfat       x86_64       1.3.0-2.fc30          rpmfusion-free        43 k

## Transaction Summary

Install  1 Package

Total download size: 43 k
Installed size: 103 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:

### fuse-exfat-1.3.0-2.fc30.x86_64.rpm              213 kB/s |  43 kB     00:00

Total                                           127 kB/s |  43 kB     00:00
warning: /var/cache/dnf/rpmfusion-free-529fb32abebfafff/packages/fuse-exfat-1.3.0-2.fc30.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c0aeda6e: NOKEY
RPM Fusion for Fedora 30 - Free                 1.6 MB/s | 1.7 kB     00:00
Importing GPG key 0xC0AEDA6E:
 Userid     : "RPM Fusion free repository for Fedora (30) "
 Fingerprint: 80C3 B2C6 E727 F3E0 92B4 73E0 3DF2 CE43 C0AE DA6E
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-30
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Installing       : fuse-exfat-1.3.0-2.fc30.x86_64                         1/1 
  Running scriptlet: fuse-exfat-1.3.0-2.fc30.x86_64                         1/1 
  Verifying        : fuse-exfat-1.3.0-2.fc30.x86_64                         1/1

Installed:
  fuse-exfat-1.3.0-2.fc30.x86_64

Complete!
[michaelmeyer@localhost ~]$